# ASP.NET virtual directory error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I set up virtual directory in IIS 6. The asp.net setting for my application pool is 4.0.

When I try to access my site I get the following error.

> Server Application Unavailable
>
> The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is
>   currently unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web
>   browser to retry your request.
>
> Administrator Note: An error message detailing the cause of this
>   specific request failure can be found in the application event log of
>   the web server. Please review this log entry to discover what caused
>   this error to occur.

When I check the event application log I get the error below.

> Failed to execute request because the App-Domain could not be created. Error: 0x80070005 Access is denied.

It looks like some sort of permissions error but I can't figure out what. Anyone have any ideas?
For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**ProcMon**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from Microsoft to trace the file access of your web server worker process (aspnet_wp.exe on XP, w3wp.exe on Win7, 2003, 2008).  If you filter where **Process Name** contains one of those two EXE names, you will eventually see an **ACCESS DENIED** entry in the status column.  This will tell you what folder/file that your web server app cannot access or open.

**Tip:** for easier reading of results, turn off the registry and network tracing in ProcMon before doing your test.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving the IIS_WPG group (or whatever group the application is running as) read/write access to you app directory and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your pool is set as .NET 4 framework but is your application set to using .NET 4?

Verify the ASP.NET tab is set to correction version on your virtual directory properties:

[image: Application Properties ASP.NET Tab]

Also check to see that your ASP.NET user has the correct access by:

1. Right click the website folder in IIS
2. Select Permissions
3. Select Network Service
4. Permit read access to the user that the ASP.NET process runs as.

You are probably using a custom user or else the persmissions would most likely be correct out of the box.